# Behavior Issue in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, behavior

I am confused why the behavior part doesn't show up in my google analytics account, this part is totally missed, does anybody know what should I do?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In **Google Analytics 4** there aren't the same Universal Analytics reports. The data model is different and currently the interface has few reports, however you can create them from **Analysis** by entering the dimensions and metrics you want.